# Send a message through a user specified gmail account

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am making an email client. I want a user to input their Google credentials and be able to send messages to other emails. I would do this with `nodemailer`, but Google doesn't seem to allow nodemailer to send messages with just a username and password. Here is an example of what I tried to do:

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

async function main() {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: 'divine@gmail.com',
      pass: '******',
    },
  });

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Divine" <divine@gmail.com>',
    to: 'info@example.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Hello world?',
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>',
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Node.js v18.12.1
PS C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient> node index
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l19-20020a170902f69300b00177efb56475sm24894649plg.85 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1542:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:546:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:953:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
    at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\divine\Programming\Node.js\EmailClient\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l19-20020a170902f69300b00177efb56475sm24894649plg.85 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

Is there a type of google auth I can use, or some way for a user to configure nodemailer to send emails from their gmail without adding application tokens?

Also, I tried to allow non secure apps to access my Gmail as a solution, but this also didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

first of all go your google account then go to step verification and then click and your email password
second step go to security option and click app password then select your device and windows and click generate
then which code generate copy and pest your old password which written your code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).